# OSX bash how to type unicode character

Tags: bash

How can i type unicode character on terminal on OSX? On a linux bash I could do it using control-shift-u and it works.

I am running Mavericks.

Is the shortcut reserved for something else

Answer (score 0):

Try `command-option-t` ? I found this [on wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input)